# How do I enable screen compatibility mode in android >11

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an app that is quite old and still has to support Android 1.5 (API version 3) devices.

For some reason the screen compatibility mode has stopped running and I can't figure out why. It did work fine on honeycomb devices.

The result I am getting is that that the app is zoomed (i.e. all elements are oversized) instead of being stretched (all my activity use relative layouts so they all stretch fine - and it was working!).

In My Manifest I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

and

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" />
```

I have tried adding `android:xlargeScreens="true"` but to not avail.

The thing I cant figure out is why the compatibility mode button has disappeared for this app. Is there something in the manifest that can do that?

I have also tried :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I mamaged to get it to stretch by using an app called "Spare parts" to disable compatability mode. but really what i want si for thecompatability button (on the notification bar) to display. I tried changing the compatability mode settings in manage applications but this didnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your application target is API version 11, which means that the screen compatibility chooser won't show up. Try with a lower target version, i.e. version 10 (Android 2.3).

Comment: Yeah thats not it unfortunately, if you look at the original version there is no targetSDK. i have no target version in the original and the compatability button is still gone. I have since tried with lower targetSDK as well as removing it, but no success in getting the compatability button (on the notification bar) to show

Comment: How can you not have a target API?

Comment: the api build target with is 8. that's not what i was talking about. the targetSdkVersion is just a an attribute to say it was tested on that version - it isn't required.